# bluemix realtime speech to text with HLS

Tags: real-time, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, http-live-streaming

I have a working app that uses the Bluemix Speech to Text API to provide closed captions for Http Live Streaming sources.  However, there is some delay with parsing the sound from the ts files.  My code is as follows:

```
videoProps.stream = WatsonSpeechToText.recognizeElement({
    element: myMediaElement,
    token: videoProps.ctx.token,
    muteSource: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    model:videoProps.ctx.currentModel,
    timestamps: true,
    profanity_filter: true,
    inactivity_timeout: -1,
    continuous: true
})
.pipe(new WatsonSpeechToText.FormatStream());

videoProps.stream.on("result", function(result) {
    //do something
}
```

Is there a faster API to use that gets me closer to realtime?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Aaron,

Which model are you using? English Broadband model? The speed depends a lot on the quality of the recording. What is the real time factor you are getting (RTF = decoding time/audio time). Which audio format? Please try feeding your file through our demo. When I speak to it I always get faster than real time recognition.

Dani

Answer (score 0):

Open source implementation based on Kaldi like this [CloudASR](https://www.cloudasr.com/demo) could run much faster than realtime, you can also tune the system to balance between speed and accuracy.. You'll have to maintain your server cloud though.

Comment: What concern if you run this in your own cloud. It's much better than to send data to IBM.

Answer (score 0):

The Watson Speech-to-Text service API provides different input models with different performance characteristics. Depending on the quality of the audio, the BroadbandModel is slightly faster than real-time, but the  NarrowBand is slightly slower than real-time.  Which model are you using? IF you're not already using the BroadbandModel, try that one, since that should be more appropriate for a captioning application, assuming that the audio is also streaming in realtime.

You can see more information about these models and their characteristics in the documentation at http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.shtml#models